# Filezilla - need to copy items from server to desktop

Tags: ftp, filezilla

This is probably really simply and obvious, but I'm not very familiar with Filezilla and can't afford a mistake. 
I need to copy a file from the server to my desktop without actually removing it from the server - the live site needs to remain live as it currently stands. There is no "Copy" option, so I'm wondering if "Download" is the option I need to use.. but I need to ensure that "Downloading" the files will not actually remove them from the server.

Basically, I need to save a copy of the site without actually disturbing or disrupting it online.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open  fileZilla, Connect to your server, you will see Remote Site and Local site. Navigate to your desktop on local site window( this will change the location where the file will be downloaded). Double click/(right click and select download) on the file you want to download on the remote site window.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting "Download" or doubleclicking the file will not delete it from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Try to select the folder or the file, and drop it on your desktop folder on the left side !

It should be good !