# How to open our local program(npptfp) in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I am maintaining a website, and want to open local program (npptfp) in sublime text 3. like notepad ++ there is a feature called "local program" or npptfp in it setting. How can i open the local program in sublime text 3 ?

Comment: i mean npptfp sir. i am sorry my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the link about how to install and user FTP files in the sublime 3

- https://artisansweb.net/use-ftpsftp-sublime-text/

  https://medium.com/@softxide/installing-ftp-plugin-in-sublime-text-3-2-19da27f2a98a

Comment: thanks sir. I've done this step.  Can we download all the project of  server to our local sir ? because i wanna run it in my local..

Comment: @ChrolloLucifer   Yes, you can do it. Run project locally. If you can access the folder you can download it easily.

Comment: how do i download those data ? i can't find any download feature there sir.
Like in FileZilla, there is a feature download when we right click on selected data.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486878/filezilla-need-to-copy-items-from-server-to-desktop) will answer your question.

Comment: That answered used in FileZilla. My question is from Sublime Text 3 sir. becaues i just retrieved the project from using Sublime SFTP, but unfortunately i can save/download those data into my local.